# Pgn crash course

Tags: pgn

Where I can find a fast smart *pgn file* format help ? You can find [here](http://www6.chessclub.com/help/PGN-spec) the complete headache details of the format.

Comment: Consider expanding your question a bit. What do you mean by fast? Just a high-level overview or something that reads nicer on the eyes than the spec/standards? For instance, would you be requiring this for programming/software development etc.?

Comment: @shivsky something that reads nicer for manually editing files (correctly of course). But for software development I would do the same: initially it must work for simple `pgn files`, only the final release should work over the spec, maybe (I tested 2 sites today that don't know about variations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a short good introduction (variations and `NAG`s included): http://www.enpassant.dk/chess/palview/manual/pgn.htm, the *PGN Basics* section.

Comment: I accepted my own answer after more than two weeks without another. I'll try to keep this question up-to-date.